# Spring Cloud data Flow on CloudFoundry

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have pushed the 1.2.2 version of spring cloud data flow server into PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry). I registered an app using maven but creating a task from the App using Flo UI fails with following exception trace, they are a bit unintelligible but looks like there is a ConnectException when trying to connect to default config server at http://localhost:8888. I do not need a config server for now. How do I get rid of this and get on with life? -

By the way I am trying to create an on-demand PCF microservice based parser for my Org.

Now I am able to create a task but I get this when I try to launch the task - CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008): The request is semantically invalid: Task must have a droplet. Specify droplet or assign current droplet to app.

Following are the logs -

2017-07-13T15:20:12.575+05:30 [RTR/0] [OUT] data-flow-server.apps.titan.lab.emc.com - [2017-07-13T09:50:12.544+0000] "GET /tasks/definitions?page=0&size=10&sort=DEFINITION_NAME,DEFINITION,ASC HTTP/1.0" 200 0 682 "https://data-flow-server.apps.titan.lab.emc.com/dashboard/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" "172.16.7.103:57574" "172.16.4.167:62442" x_forwarded_for:"-" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"3525c07a-ccf4-48b9-4d90-0c40658fa696" response_time:0.030533986 app_id:"405aad06-0bda-4b73-b0c4-b8d03a131fa5" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"deed52aa152480b0" x_b3_spanid:"deed52aa152480b0" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
2017-07-13T15:20:14.133+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.cloudfoundry.client.v3.ClientV3Exception: CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008): The request is semantically invalid: Task must have a droplet. Specify droplet or assign current droplet to app.
2017-07-13T15:20:14.133+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-07-13 09:50:14.132 ERROR 15 --- [ry-client-nio-1] s.c.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher : Task sampleDataFlowTask launch failed
2017-07-13T15:20:14.133+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$3(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:65) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.14.0.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.133+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$10(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:108) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.14.0.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.133+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.133+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsing$UsingFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsing.java:351) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:428) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:198) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:338) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:962) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoReduceSeed$ReduceSeedSubscriber.onComplete(MonoReduceSeed.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:375) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:343) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onHandlerTerminate(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:566) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:125) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240) ~[netty-handler-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041) ~[netty-handler-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek] :
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1400)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.cloudfoundry.reactor.client.v3.tasks.ReactorTasks.create(ReactorTasks.java:58)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.requestCreateTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:170)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.launchTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:144)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.lambda$launch$0(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:91)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:120)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:962)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain$ThenMapInner.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:237)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:173)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:235)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:207)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:322)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.134+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:316)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:581)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:125)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.http.HttpOperations.lambda$static$3(HttpOperations.java:261)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.ReactorNetty$ExtractorHandler.channelRead(ReactorNetty.java:328)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
2017-07-13T15:20:14.135+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] |_ Mono.checkpoint(ReactorTasks.java:58)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$10(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:108) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.14.0.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2017-07-13 09:50:14.143 ERROR 15 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice : Caught exception while handling a request
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.cloudfoundry.client.v3.ClientV3Exception: CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008): The request is semantically invalid: Task must have a droplet. Specify droplet or assign current droplet to app.
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.cloudfoundry.reactor.util.ErrorPayloadMapper.lambda$null$3(ErrorPayloadMapper.java:65) ~[cloudfoundry-client-reactor-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.14.0.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsing$UsingFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsing.java:351) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:428) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:962) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoReduceSeed$ReduceSeedSubscriber.onComplete(MonoReduceSeed.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.7.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:375) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:198) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:338) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:343) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.145+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onHandlerTerminate(ChannelOperations.java:419) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:566) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:125) ~[reactor-netty-0.6.4.RELEASE.jar!/:0.6.4.RELEASE]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240) ~[netty-handler-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041) ~[netty-handler-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar!/:4.1.9.Final]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek] :
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.Mono.checkpoint(Mono.java:1400)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.cloudfoundry.reactor.client.v3.tasks.ReactorTasks.create(ReactorTasks.java:58)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.requestCreateTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:170)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.launchTask(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:144)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.lambda$launch$0(CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher.java:91)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:120)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:962)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoThenMap$ThenMapMain$ThenMapInner.onNext(MonoThenMap.java:237)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:173)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:235)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:207)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:322)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:316)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:581)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:125)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.http.HttpOperations.lambda$static$3(HttpOperations.java:261)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.146+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] reactor.ipc.netty.ReactorNetty$ExtractorHandler.channelRead(ReactorNetty.java:328)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1240)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1041)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
2017-07-13T15:20:14.147+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do. Are you registering a Task app from the GUI? Are you using the composed task feature from the GUI? More details on what is that you're trying would help. Also, the config-server is logged as a WARN - it is not the actual error - the caused-by is missing in the attached log. It'd help if you can share the entire stacktrace as a file attached or as gist.

Comment: Yes I have registered a task App using GUI. And I am trying to create a task and then launch it again from the UI.

Comment: Following is the exception looks like it's not picking up our remote repo but defaulting to spring repo.
2017-07-10T14:26:15.481+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.dell.gs.sizer.parser:sizer-solaris-parser-dataflow:jar:0.0.9 in springRepo (https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot) VCAP Vars -SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON { "maven": { "local-repository": null, "remote-repositories": { "repo1": { "url": "https://cksvnprd03.isus.emc.com/artifactory/libs-release-local", "auth": { "username": "bla", "password":"bla" }}}}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last comment and in reviewing `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` property, it seems like it is an invalid JSON. It is missing a curly brace and as well as an invalid `;` character embedded in it.

If the format is invalid, the `java-buildpack` won't be able to auto-reconfigure and flat them out as Boot properties. Here's the well-formed JSON for reference.

> {
>     "maven": {
>       "local-repository": "local",
>       "remote-repositories": {
>         "repo1": {
>           "url": "https://cksvnprd03.isus.emc.com/artifactory/libs-release-local",
>           "auth": {
>             "username": "bla",
>             "password": "bla"
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }

Note: if the repository is behind the firewall, please make sure to supply the [proxy settings](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_configure_maven_properties) as well.

Comment: INSERT into TASK_EXECUTION(TASK_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, TASK_NAME, LAST_UPDATED, EXTERNAL_EXECUTION_ID, PARENT_EXECUTION_ID)values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), parameters [4,<null>,'sampleDataFlowTask','2017-07-11 09:23:44.12',<null>,<null>]
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback;bad SQL grammar [INSERT into TASK_EXECUTION(TASK_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, TASK_NAME, LAST_UPDATED, EXTERNAL_EXECUTION_ID, PARENT_EXECUTION_ID)values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)];nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:76145) Unknown column 'PARENT_EXECUTION_ID' in 'field list'

Comment: Getting this when I run the task the version of server I am using is - spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar the DAO class JdbcTaskExecutionDao.class is in spring-cloud-task-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar packaged within the parent server Jar.

Comment: By the way I corrected the issue with SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON and was able to create a task.

Comment: OK we deleted the schema created again and that worked now failing with this - CF-AppInvalid(100001): The app is invalid: custom buildpacks are disabled

Comment: It is not very easy to troubleshoot without any other details. What's on your `manifest.yml`? What's your task definition? Are you expected to run the task with a custom buildpack? If so, how are you supplying it?

Comment: If the original question related to maven repo is resolved, please consider closing this out. That way, it will be easy for the rest of the community to review the specific problem and solution.

Comment: Hi We set a java buildpack using env vars in CF and we could proceed again to fail with this - org.cloudfoundry.client.v3.ClientV3Exception: CF-FeatureDisabled(330002): Feature Disabled: task_creation. Tried solutions mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897513/unable-to-launch-task-on-spring-cloud-data-flow-pivotal-cloud-foundry. Did not work.

Comment: I set SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_EXPERIMENTAL_TASKSENABLED to true. Did not work same exception.

Comment: `CF-FeatureDisabled` is an error from CF. It has nothing to do with SCDF. FWIW, Tasks in PCF was GA'd in PCF 1.9 release. It could be that you're on older releases of PCF, which doesn't support them yet.

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve my problem of Feature Disabled by using this command by my CF admin - 'cf enable-feature-flag task_creation'. My Cf admin wasn't very happy about it as its an experimental feature.

Comment: I solved the MySQl table/column mismatch issue by dropping the schema and recreating the mysql instance attached to data-flow server. This happenned due to mismatch in spring-cloud-task-core version. Please use 1.1.2+ associated to spring boot starter 1.5.2.RELEASE. A new column called parent_execution_id.

Comment: Solved the app invalid option due to custom buildpack not found by providing buildpack SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_TASK_BUILDPACK to java_buildpack_offline. This is VCAP env variable in dataflow server.

Comment: Still getting a CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008): The request is semantically invalid: Task must have a droplet. Specify droplet or assign current droplet to app error. Please refer to another thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077525/unable-to-deploy-run-tasks-on-pivotal-cf-from-spring-cloud-dataflow-container-er

Comment: So far, you're yet to confirm the PCF version. Can you please make sure you share the details before asking questions? The tasks in PCF were experimental until 1.8 - it has been GA'd since 1.9 - the latest PCF release is 1.11. Which version are you on?!

Comment: The PCF version we are using v1.11

Answer (score 0):

Data Flow Server Implementation

Name    spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry
Version 1.2.2.RELEASE
Enabled Features

Analytics Y 
Streams Y
Tasks   Y

Security Information

Authentication Enabled  X
Authorization Enabled   X
Form Login              X
Authenticated           X
Username    N/A
Roles   []

Version Information

Implementation  1.2.2.RELEASE (spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry)
Core    1.2.2.RELEASE (Spring Cloud Data Flow Core)
Dashboard   1.2.1.RELEASE (Spring Cloud Dataflow UI)
Runtime Environment - App Deployer

Implementation Version  1.2.1.RELEASE
Name    CloudFoundryAppDeployer
Spi Version 1.2.1.RELEASE
Java Version    1.8.0_131
Platform Api Version    2.65.0
Platform Client Version 2.14.0.RELEASE
Platform Host Version   unknown
Platform Type   Cloud Foundry
Spring Boot Version 1.5.4.RELEASE
Spring Version  4.3.9.RELEASE
Platform-specific Information of the App Deployer

API Endpoint    https://api.system.titan.lab.emc.com
Runtime Environment - Task Launcher

ImplementationVersion   1.2.1.RELEASE
Name    CloudFoundry2630AndLaterTaskLauncher
Spi Version 1.2.1.RELEASE
Java Version    1.8.0_131
Platform Api Version    2.65.0
Platform Client Version 2.14.0.RELEASE
Platform Host Version   unknown
Platform Type   Cloud Foundry
Spring Boot Version 1.5.4.RELEASE
Spring Version  4.3.9.RELEASE
Platform-specific Information of the Task Launcher

API Endpoint    https://api.system.titan.lab.emc.com

PCF version 1.11